# Passing attribute from one class to another

Tags: python, class, oop

Just started OOP in python. Can't really get my head over it.

So my question is how do I use method in another class. I know it works, just can't seem to understand the logic.

Question file:

```
class Question():    # ** !!! Why do I need this line? !!!**
    def __init__(self,text,answer):
        self.text=text
        self.answer=answer
```

Quiz file:

```
class QuizBrain:
    def __init__(self,q_list): #putting on zero question number and importing list etc
        self.question_number=0
        self.question_list=q_list

    def next_question(self):
        current_question=self.question_list[self.question_number]
        self.question_number+=1
        # ** How do I use .text attribute in different file without calling the class? **
        self.user_input=input(f'Q{self.question_number}: {current_question.text} True/False')

    def still_has_question(self):
        return self.question_number<len(self.question_list)
```

File I get data from:

```
question_data = ['random data','random data']
```

MAIN file:

```
from question_model import Question
from data import question_data
from quiz_brain import QuizBrain

question_bank=[]
for question in question_data:
    new_question=Question(question['text'],question['answer'])
    question_bank.append(new_question)

quiz=QuizBrain(question_bank)
quiz.next_question()
while quiz.still_has_question():
    quiz.next_question()
```

So basically my question might seem kinda silly, but how do I pass `.text` attribute from one class to another? Why does it print out memory location of `current_question` without the `.text` attribute? Currently my brain is a mush after starting OOP...

Comment: Your code is creating a list of `Question` instances which each have a `.text` **attribute**. You print that attribute in the `next_question()` method because you have an instance of `Question` in `current_question` and thus `current_question.text` accesses the `text` attribute.

Comment: btw the line: `class Question():` just gives the class a name.

Comment: `class Question():` tells Python you are about to define a class named `Question` (you don't need the `()`, btw).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inherit Question class from QuizBrain class.

```
class Question:   
    def __init__(self, text, answer):
        self.text=text
        self.answer=answer

class QuizBrain(Question): # You need to pass Question class as an argument
    def __init__(self,q_list):
        Question.__init__(self, text, answer) # This is the same __init__ function from the Question class
```

Now you can use .text attribute from another class just like this:

```
var = QuizBrain("Your arguments")
print(var.text)
```